# Client Login before accessing the internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, gateway

I wanted to create an internet gateway server where the client connecting to my network must enter a username and password, where the server checks if username and password is correct before they can access the internet. More like AUTHENTICATION via web browser.

SETUP IS LIKE THIS:

INTERNET <--> GATEWAY SERVER <--> WIFI ROUTER <--> (CLIENTS connected)

ADD:

->When not authenticated, the client will be redirected to the local server login page. When authenticated, client can access internet.

->If user deletes cookies, user will be redirected to the local server login page until authenticated again.

I don't know if it is related, but it is like this, but with client login: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926001

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) for this purpose. It is easy to implement basic [authentication](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples#Authentication) and [redirect](http://www.mail-archive.com/squid-users@squid-cache.org/msg63653.html) upon failure.

> Squid is a caching proxy for the Web supporting HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and more. It reduces bandwidth and improves response times by caching and reusing frequently-requested web pages. Squid has extensive access controls and makes a great server accelerator. It runs on most available operating systems, including Windows and is licensed under the GNU GPL.

Comment: Will this work side by side with webmin?

Comment: @weyhei of course. The only requirement is to configure separate tcp ports for both tools.